# Trouble installing mysqlclient via pip

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working on a Django (1.9.2) project where I need to connect to a MySQl database, and I'm trying to use the recommended mysqlclient library. However, when I attempt installation via `pip install mysqlclient` I get the following error:

> ```
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> sh: mysql_config: command not found
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/private/var/folders/v9/vxdt4wms0_qgm9n10rt74p8m0000gn/T/pip-build-Xh__3p/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
>     metadata, options = get_config()
>   File "setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
>     libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
>   File "setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
>     raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
> EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
> ```

Where do I need to create this missing `mysql_config`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For mac:

- `brew install mysql`
- `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`
- `pip install mysqlclient`

It works for me.

```
➜ which mysql_config    
/usr/local/bin/mysql_config
```

For ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev (or libmariadbclient-dev)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have mysql installed on my system though. I've just never used it with Django.

Comment: But apparently that `export` step was what I'm missing.

Comment: @wogsland Wesll,I suggest you check out your environment variable,and make sure they all in the $PATH environment variable.

Comment: Weird, because I use `mysql` from the command line all the time.